# AWS Cognito single use access token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to issue access tokens that are valid for a single use? My use case is to invoke Lambda functions from browser but want to restrict the number of invocations to one per token.

If a short lived token is issued then there is still potential for it to be used for multiple invocations.

I am using DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities to issue the temporary tokens.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing with AWS Cognito.

You can implement a custom Authorizer with API Gateway to manage your invocations count. If the same URL accessed more than once, you can deny the service.

More info on Custom Authorizers.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Cognito is not designed for that, however you could achieve this by 
throwing undesired expensive computation at it:

1. Your Api/app adds the user on behalf of the admin.
2. Your api/app removes the `confirmed` user after certain amount of time.

You could see that this approach is not feasible even for low number of users.

**Better approach, if the routes are unique (still using Cognito)**

1. Same as above.
2. You have the list of routes, as a bucket names, in S3; each has a file 
   that consists, something like

   {
       accessed: false
   }

If the user uses the token to access the route your app check for the above, grand 
the access, and sets it to true. You could even not have the above file and just the 
buckets; that represents the routes and gets removed upon being accessed.

**Much Better approach**

1. The application could generate/verify, short expiry JWT tokens, for supporting short lived authorized users. The downside here is that the development time which might lead to 
   security risks if the application is not throughly tested.

2.Same as the above approach (using S3).

Answer (score 0):

For limiting usage, I think the best approach will be using usage plans.

It is not a token responsibility to restrict usage, API Key is there for that purpose.

Have a look at this AWS page.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html